# Meaning of $\int y dx +x dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

What does it mean to take an integral:
$\int y dx + xdy$

I would guess that this means that this integral over a region multiplies the infinitely small increments of $x$ ($\Delta x$) by $y$ and the infinitely small increments of $y$ ($\Delta y$) by x, but I still can't really picture what this integral does.

Is it the same as a double integral?

I'm sorry for how vague this question is, but any material you can provide me with would be appreciated.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int ydx+xdy = \int <y, x>\cdot <dx, dy> = \int \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$$

You can see that the corresponding definite integral gives work done by the force field $\textbf{F} = <y, x>$

Comment: I see. So we're taking a vector field (which could represent force) and then integrating will give us the sum of force * distance at every location. I'm actually going over line integrals right now, so it makes sense that work would be the application because things move over lines and not entire regions (if that makes sense). Thanks for your answer. Sorry if this was a dumb question, but I couldn't find the reason in my calculus book.